# Mac Reset Password Prompt

Tags: macos, passwords, reset

So I will do my best to explain what I am looking for assistance with.

So I am looking for a way to create a password reset prompt similar to what is out there for Windows. For example when a password expires on a domain for Windows it will ask for the current password and and a new password.

Here is a screenshot of what I am referring to: http://moritzlaw.osu.edu/technology/training/Windows7/PasswordPrompt.jpg

I am looking for a way to do the samething on a Mac that is NOT on a domain. I am looking to create some type of tool or script to be ran that will make it so the next time a user signs on, they have to change their password.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

loginwindow does this automatically when a user's password expires; the only trick is to make a local user's password expire. You can do this with the `pwpolicy` command:

```
pwpolicy -a adminuser -u usertoforcechange -setpolicy "newPasswordRequired=1"
```

There are a bunch of policies you can set, including minimum length, at least one letter, at least one digit, expiration period, etc. See the [pwpolicy man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/pwpolicy.8.html) for details.

Comment: `newPasswordRequired` is marked as deprecated now. How should we do this in 2019?

Answer (score 1):

You can force password expiration on non-activeDirectory non-OpenDirectory accounts by changing the default setting in the com.apple.loginwindow plist.  NUMBER should be 0 if you want it expired now, or NUMBER for the number of days you want passwords to be valid for.

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow PasswordExpirationDays NUMBER
```

Comment: There may be an option in `sudo chpass username` but I don't see it in the default options